# Get Django GeometryField's coordinates with values()

Tags: django, json, gis, postgis, geodjango

I have a model with a `GeometryField`. Like this -

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geo_models

class School(BaseModel):
    # Some fields
    centroid = geo_models.GeometryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And I'm filtering the values with the `values()` method because I have to generate a JSON out of the QuerySet -

```
class SearchView(View, JSONResponseMixin):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        params = self.request.GET
        results = {}
        schools = School.objects.values('id', 'code', 'name')
        # More stuff here
```

But I need to return the latitude and longitude in the JSON too. Putting `centroid` in `values()` just returns the encrypted hex value. How do I get it to spit the coordinates out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, had to use the `ST_AsGeoJSON()` function of PostGIS like this -

```
schools = School.objects.extra(
    select={
        'centroid': 'ST_AsGeoJSON("schools_school"."centroid")'
    }
).values('code', 'name', 'centroid')
```

As a result, I get the JSON compatible data -

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "code": "12345678",
            "centroid": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[75.32559653,16.906422997]}",
            "name": "SCHOOL NAME"
        },
        // more
    ]
}
```

I'd still have to deserialize it on client side, but I guess that's doable and acceptable. At least I get JSON.