# How to improve performance when load large data from database and convert to JSON

Tags: python, django, json, python-2.7, django-models

I write a Djano application which deals with financial data process.
I have to load large data(more than 1000000 records) from MySQL table, and convert the records to JSON data in django views as following:

```
trades = MtgoxTrade.objects.all()
data = []
for trade in trades:
            js = dict()
            js['time']= trade.time
            js['price']= trade.price
            js['amount']= trade.amount
            js['type']= trade.type
            data.append(js)
return data
```

The problem is that the FOR loop is very slow(which takes more than 9 seconds for 200000 records), is there any effective way to convert DB records to JSON format data in Python?

**Updated: I have run code according to Mike Housky's answer in my ENV(ActivePython2.7,Win7) With code changes and result as**:

```
def create_data(n):
    from api.models import MtgoxTrade
    result = MtgoxTrade.objects.all()

    return result


  Build ............ 0.330999851227
  For loop ......... 7.98400020599
  List Comp. ....... 0.457000017166
  Ratio ............ 0.0572394796312
  For loop 2 ....... 0.381999969482
  Ratio ............ 0.047845686326
```

You will find the for loop takes about 8 seconds! And if i comment out the For loop,then List Comp also takes such time as:

```
Times:
  Build ............ 0.343000173569
  List Comp. ....... 7.57099986076
  For loop 2 ....... 0.375999927521
```

**My new question is that whether the for loop will touch the database? But i did not see any DB access log. So strange!**

Comment: You can look at the problem from the other side. You can do all expensive tasks asynchronously using Celery

Comment: Celery is good for async programming, but my case prefer sync design for now, maybe check it in future:)Thanks~

Comment: Set `DEBUG = False` and try again.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, DEBUG=False could not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here are several tips/things to try.

Since you need to make a JSON-string from the queryset eventually, use django's built-in [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.core import serializers

data = serializers.serialize("json", 
                             MtgoxTrade.objects.all(), 
                             fields=('time','price','amount','type'))
```

You can make serialization faster by using [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) or [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) modules. See [SERIALIZATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#serialization-modules) setting.

Also, instead of getting all the field values from the record, be explicit and get only what you need to serialize:

```
MtgoxTrade.objects.all().values('time','price','amount','type')
```

Also, you may want to use [iterator()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator) method of a queryset:

> ...For a QuerySet which returns a large number of objects that you
>   only need to access once, this can result in better performance and a
>   significant reduction in memory...

Also, you can split your huge queryset into batches, see: [Batch querysets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1170/).

Also see:

- [Why is iterating through a large Django QuerySet consuming massive amounts of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222176/why-is-iterating-through-a-large-django-queryset-consuming-massive-amounts-of-me)
- [Memory efficient Django Queryset Iterator](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/)
- [django: control json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129794/django-control-json-serialization)

Comment: Sad but this don't seem to work when you're using a `GeometryField`. Just faced [one such situation today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903652/get-django-geometryfields-coordinates-with-values).

Comment: I have used django serializers, but seems also no performance boost. And my MtgoxTrade table only have the above 4 fields.

Comment: "trades = MtgoxTrade.objects.all()" only take less than 1 second, but the for loop takes more than 8 seconds!

Comment: Yes. "MtgoxTrade.objects.all().values('time','price','amount','type')" this way does boost performance with 20% ratios!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension as that prevents many `dict()` and `append()` calls:

```
trades = MtgoxTrade.objects.all()
data = [{'time': trade.time, 'price': trade.price, 'amount': trade.amount, 'type': trade.type}
        for trade in trades]
return data
```

Function calls are expensive in Python so you should aim to avoid them in slow loops.

Comment: A list comprehension does not give you any significant speedup here.

Comment: Maybe this is implementation-dependent. On Win7, CPython 2.7.3 and 3.3.0 I see improvements of 25% or more for list comprehension over the for loop. I'll post the code in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in support of Simeon Visser's observation.  I ran the following code:

```
import gc, random, time
if "xrange" not in dir(__builtins__):
    xrange = range

class DataObject(object):
    def __init__(self, time, price, amount, type):
        self.time = time
        self.price = price
        self.amount = amount
        self.type = type

def create_data(n):
    result = []
    for index in xrange(n):
        s = str(index);
        result.append(DataObject("T"+s, "P"+s, "A"+s, "ty"+s))
    return result

def convert1(trades):
    data = []
    for trade in trades:
                js = dict()
                js['time']= trade.time
                js['price']= trade.price
                js['amount']= trade.amount
                js['type']= trade.type
                data.append(js)
    return data

def convert2(trades):
    data = [{'time': trade.time, 'price': trade.price, 'amount': trade.amount, 'type': trade.type}
        for trade in trades]
    return data

def convert3(trades):
    ndata = len(trades)
    data = ndata*[None]
    for index in xrange(ndata):
        t = trades[index]
        js = dict()
        js['time']= t.time
        js['price']= t.price
        js['amount']= t.amount
        js['type']= t.type
        #js = {"time" : t.time, "price" : t.price, "amount" : t.amount, "type" : t.type}
    return data

def main(n=1000000):

    t0s = time.time()
    trades = create_data(n);
    t0f = time.time()
    t0 = t0f - t0s

    gc.disable()

    t1s = time.time()
    jtrades1 = convert1(trades)
    t1f = time.time()
    t1 = t1f - t1s

    t2s = time.time()
    jtrades2 = convert2(trades)
    t2f = time.time()
    t2 = t2f - t2s

    t3s = time.time()
    jtrades3 = convert3(trades)
    t3f = time.time()
    t3 = t3f - t3s

    gc.enable()

    print ("Times:")
    print ("  Build ............ " + str(t0))
    print ("  For loop ......... " + str(t1))
    print ("  List Comp. ....... " + str(t2))
    print ("  Ratio ............ " + str(t2/t1))
    print ("  For loop 2 ....... " + str(t3))
    print ("  Ratio ............ " + str(t3/t1))

main()
```

Results on Win7, Core 2 Duo 3.0GHz:
Python 2.7.3:

```
Times:
  Build ............ 2.95600008965
  For loop ......... 0.699999809265
  List Comp. ....... 0.512000083923
  Ratio ............ 0.731428890618
  For loop 2 ....... 0.609999895096
  Ratio ............ 0.871428659011
```

Python 3.3.0:

```
Times:
  Build ............ 3.4320058822631836
  For loop ......... 1.0200011730194092
  List Comp. ....... 0.7500009536743164
  Ratio ............ 0.7352942070195492
  For loop 2 ....... 0.9500019550323486
  Ratio ............ 0.9313733946208623
```

Those vary a bit, even with GC disabled (much more variance with GC enabled, but about the same results).  The third conversion timing shows that a fair-sized chunk of the saved time comes from not calling .append() a million times.

Ignore the "For loop 2" times.  This version has a bug and I am out of time to fix it for now.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the performance loss happens while fetching the data from the database or inside the loop.

There is no real option for giving you a significant speedup - also not using a list comprehension as noticed above.

However there is a huge difference in performance between Python 2 and 3.

A simple benchmark showed me that the for-loop is roughly 2,5 times faster with Python 3.3 (using some simple benchmark like the following):

```
import time

ts = time.time()
data = list()
for i in range(1000000):
    d = {}
    d['a'] = 1
    d['b'] = 2
    d['c'] = 3
    d['d'] = 4
    d['a'] = 5
    data.append(d)

print(time.time() - ts)



/opt/python-3.3.0/bin/python3 foo2.py 
0.5906929969787598

python2.6 foo2.py 
1.74390792847

python2.7 foo2.py 
0.673550128937
```

You will also note that there is a significant performance difference between Python 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: I use Python2.7, your sample code run with less than 1 second, while my loop run more than 8 seconds only with 200000 records?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth trying to do a raw query against the database because a Model puts a lot of extra boilerplate code into fields (I belive that fields are properties) and like previously mentioned function calls are expensive. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), there is an example at the bottom of the page that uses dictfetchall which seems like the thing you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [values method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values). It will return an iterable of dicts instead of model objects, so you don't have to create a lot of intermediate data structures. Your code could be reduced to

```
return MtgoxTrade.objects.values('time', 'price', 'amount', 'type')
```